# local to local connections with TIME_WAIT state in centos

Tags: centos, ip, port

I have centos7 host with 2 interfaces:

```
lo: 127.0.0.1
eth0: 10.0.0.11
```

when I am looking for 'local to local' connections in `netstat -apeen` output or in /proc/net/tcp file, I can see only **one line** for TIME_WAIT connection, for example (**case 1**):

```
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:6388   127.0.0.1:13444   TIME_WAIT
```

at the same time if state ESTABLISHED I can see **2 lines** accordingly, see examples (**case 2**):

```
tcp     0      0 127.0.0.1:11514         127.0.0.1:24156         ESTABLISHED 
tcp     0      0 127.0.0.1:24156         127.0.0.1:11514         ESTABLISHED
```

or

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.11:81          10.0.0.11:52162       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.11:52162       10.0.0.11:81          ESTABLISHED
```

in both cases pair of ports busy correct?

could someone explain why 1 case having **1 line** and 2 case **2 lines** in output ?

I am trying to count total amount of busy ports on each IP address by counting 1 line - 1 port in `/proc/net/tcp` but looks like this is incorrect, is there any better way ?